# PowerShell equivalent for the "at" command

Tags: powershell

We are porting Unix scripts to PowerShell. I am totally new to PowerShell and have problem in finding replacement for the `at` command in Unix.

We have a script that is scheduled using the `at` command:

```
SEQ_NO=12; export SEQ_NO
A=R2.13575180; export A
B=R4.13575180.DAT; export B
chmod 777 R4.13575180.DAT
echo "sh R4.13575180.DAT > M.reclog " |
 at now + 2 minutes
```

`R4.13575180.DAT` would contain PowerShell commands inside. I was able to find replacements for other commands. I need to find a replacement for the `at` command. I did go through certain links, but I am still not clear. Could you suggest a replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're new to PowerShell, here is some general advice:

- Make sure you are running the latest operating system possible, to get the most recent features (eg. Windows 8.1)
- Make sure you have installed the latest Microsoft .NET Framework version (eg. [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779))

  - The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 is already included with Windows 8.1
- Make sure you are running the latest PowerShell (aka. Windows Management Framework (WMF) Core) version

  - The latest version of [WMF is 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855)
  - The WMF / PowerShell 4.0 package is built into Windows 8.1 (Windows Server 2012 R2) and is **available** for Windows 7 (Server 2008 R2)
  - WMF 4.0 is **not available** for Windows 8.0

**IMPORTANT**: The ScheduledTasks PowerShell module is available only on Windows 8.1 with the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and PowerShell version 4.0.

You're most likely looking for the PowerShell module named `ScheduledTasks`, if you want to schedule something to run in the future.

To find out what commands are in the `ScheduledTasks` module, use this command:

```
Get-Command -Module ScheduledTasks;
```

To be more specific in answer to your question, here is an example of how to create a ScheduledTask:

```
# 1. Create a trigger
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At '2013-12-30 12:00:00 AM' -Once;
# 2. Create an action
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute powershell.exe -Argument '-Command Write-Host -Object "hi";'
# 3. Create the scheduled task
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Description PowerShell;
# 4. Register the ScheduledTask
Register-ScheduledTask -InputObject $Task -TaskName PowerShell;

# 5. [Optional] View / confirm the ScheduledTask object
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName PowerShell;
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, Thank you for your reply. We use Windows 7 and PowerShell verison 2.0. Will the same be available here? Is there any other option we can use for Scheduling the task other than "ScheduledTasks" ?  Sorry if the question is little short of understanding what you have explained.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running Windows 7 / PowerShell 2.0 you might want to grab the TaskScheduler module from [PowerShellPack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack).

That will get you cmdlets for managing scheduled tasks.